# Split a large bar chart on two pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large bar chart:

[image]

I want to split it into two and print it onto two pages like the one below but with an equal scale size on both sides. The one below was done by:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)

p1 = d %>%
  slice(1:30) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "shop") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()

p2 = d %>%
  slice(31:60) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "shop") +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol = 2)
```

... but there must be a better method.

[image]

```
    structure(list(shop_id = 0:59, sales = c(1.18748097798519, 1.1114829165199, 
1.17810011157708, 1.1105671314429, 1.14905078186287, 1.12003981246235, 
1.21564666174709, 1.15465941180522, 1.05363423212192, 4.22980538523061, 
1.14609524699724, 1.14629258517034, 2.11788781921946, 1.10878590664273, 
1.25409015927959, 1.19643427265548, 1.16875260742595, 1.12583877995643, 
1.23031544141131, 1.14933266573829, 3.27678571428571, 1.17936456057661, 
1.32565919795748, 1.10656326296137, 1.2046688791673, 1.2999183252375, 
1.25932109070673, 1.29697435605414, 1.29755895214928, 1.19274758760792, 
1.19598898938262, 1.31888590877455, 1.10494526236316, 1.09051123930774, 
1.12152294853964, 1.18087090426897, 1.07843137254902, 1.16696099702306, 
1.17110381848608, 1.23638392857143, 1.16114634719286, 1.17530440584269, 
1.32659057417188, 1.28832544167812, 1.13680748798381, 1.16728427739545, 
1.19102546704664, 1.19299761883764, 1.15255413659078, 1.0783014701243, 
1.16977889616866, 1.09754011658002, 1.14348765573997, 1.16507624572476, 
1.29488430443267, 1.82311829503293, 1.12226007215443, 1.20164696665191, 
1.14407693061407, 1.16350812197207)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to get your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using `facet_wrap`. I chose to hide the facet information after the fact, but you can change that easily if you want:

```r
x <-  structure(list(shop_id = 0:59, sales = c(1.18748097798519, 1.1114829165199, 
                                               1.17810011157708, 1.1105671314429, 1.14905078186287, 1.12003981246235, 
                                               1.21564666174709, 1.15465941180522, 1.05363423212192, 4.22980538523061, 
                                               1.14609524699724, 1.14629258517034, 2.11788781921946, 1.10878590664273, 
                                               1.25409015927959, 1.19643427265548, 1.16875260742595, 1.12583877995643, 
                                               1.23031544141131, 1.14933266573829, 3.27678571428571, 1.17936456057661, 
                                               1.32565919795748, 1.10656326296137, 1.2046688791673, 1.2999183252375, 
                                               1.25932109070673, 1.29697435605414, 1.29755895214928, 1.19274758760792, 
                                               1.19598898938262, 1.31888590877455, 1.10494526236316, 1.09051123930774, 
                                               1.12152294853964, 1.18087090426897, 1.07843137254902, 1.16696099702306, 
                                               1.17110381848608, 1.23638392857143, 1.16114634719286, 1.17530440584269, 
                                               1.32659057417188, 1.28832544167812, 1.13680748798381, 1.16728427739545, 
                                               1.19102546704664, 1.19299761883764, 1.15255413659078, 1.0783014701243, 
                                               1.16977889616866, 1.09754011658002, 1.14348765573997, 1.16507624572476, 
                                               1.29488430443267, 1.82311829503293, 1.12226007215443, 1.20164696665191, 
                                               1.14407693061407, 1.16350812197207)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                               "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L))


x$rank <- rank(-x$sales)
x$group <- ifelse(x$rank <= 30, 1,2)


library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.4

ggplot(x, aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y") +
  xlab("Store") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use `slice` to subset your data and then manually set your breaks with `scale_y_continuous`.

```
data %>%
 slice(1:30) %>%
 ggplot(aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
 geom_col() +
 coord_flip() +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))

data %>%
 slice(31:60) %>%
 ggplot(aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
 geom_col() +
 coord_flip() +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))
```

[image]

You could also then turn this into a function if you're going to be using it a lot:

```
slice_and_dice <- function(data, rows) {
 data %>%
 slice(rows) %>%
 ggplot(aes(reorder(shop_id, sales), sales)) +
 geom_col() +
 coord_flip() +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))
}
```